# Android Studio : Project Structure unavailable using Gradle KTS Build Files

Tags: android-studio, project-structure, gradle-kts

Open File-> Project Structure.

Issue: It says **"Project Structure is unavailable for projects that use Gradle KTS build files. This project uses Gradle KTS build files which are not fully supported in this version of Android Studio"**

I am using the below configuration

- Android Studio : 3.5.3
- Gradle plugin : 3.5.3
- Gradle wrapper : 5.5.1

Is this the expected behavior? Can anyone provide a suggestion to fix this

Comment: check this reddit link: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/czk03u/as_35_project_structure_unavailable_for_gradle/

Answer (score 0):

Android studio 3.5.x did not support very well Gradle Kotlin DSL.
You shoud  try it on android 4.X it's way better supported.